# Help with SOQL where I get records that do not have any related tasks and events

Tags: soql

I am trying to get a count of leads to archive.

I am trying to get a count of all leads that have a 'Status Last Modified Date' of 13+ months and does not have any related Tasks/Events.

I am not sure on how to query on Tasks and Events both and I can come up with is:

```
select count(id) from Lead where Status_last_Modified_date__c < LAST_N_MONTHS:13 And Id not in(select accountid from Task)And Id not in(select accountid from Event)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. Tasks are notoriously hard to query because of the restrictions placed on them, one of them being that they can't be used in the manner you're trying to. You'll get the error:

> Entity 'task' is not supported for semi join inner selects

Also, as a side note, you meant to use WhoId instead of AccountId.

Instead, the best that you can reasonably do would be to query off the `LastActivityDate`:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Lead 
WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_MONTHS:13 AND 
  LastActivityDate = NULL
```

However, keep in mind that If the Lead has Tasks with no Due Date, this can still return false positives, so you'll need to do a review of your data. Also keep in mind that some activities are [archived](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activities_archived.htm&type=5) and won't show up in normal queries.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Trying to come up with a way to archive leads. The 'Tasks with no Due Date' would mess up the second approach. Need to understand our data.