# How to overcome inability to use anti joins when it comes to activities in order to get leads that truly have no activity?

Tags: soql, leads, archive

We are trying to integrate with a backup solution as an archival solution. In the UI, we have the ability to write a SOQL query that is to get the archival criteria on a per archival policy.

We would like to archive leads and opportunity records that have no activity.

So initially I did this:

```
select count(id) from Lead where Status_last_Modified_date__c < LAST_N_MONTHS:13 And Id not in(select whoid from Task)And Id not in(select whoid from Event)
```

That results in :

```
Entity 'task' is not supported for semi join inner selects
```

The next best approach that was [recommended](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/386879/help-with-soql-where-i-get-records-that-do-not-have-any-related-tasks-and-events/386881#386881) was to use something as follows:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Lead 
WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_MONTHS:13 AND 
  LastActivityDate = NULL
```

However that would not work if we have activities with no Due Date which we do. Also some activities are archived.

The idea here is not to get all leads per one SOQL query but to have multiple archive policies that can cover all the lead records.  Is there any other approach or SOQL we can employ to get some control over this? Thank You

Comment: Are you limited to SOQL only or do you have post-processing capability?

Comment: Only SOQL unfortunately.

Comment: Then unfortunately you may be stuck implementing a count rollup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your only option to be implementing a rollup `Activity_Count__c` field. To do so, you will have to add some custom code or implement a common tool such as `Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries` or `RollupHelper` (I have no affiliation to either). If you have the technical skills required, rolling your own is not particularly complicated. If you lack them, I strongly recommend installing one of these tools instead. If you roll your own rollup, you will also need a backfill batch.